# Solutions for fast pace of questions disappearing from MSE's front page

Tags: discussion

I've noticed that MSE is a very active site, with questions often rolling in every few minutes. It's wonderful to see so much interest in mathematics, but it can be frustrating when one's question disappears from the front page in less than an hour. (Contrast with MO, where questions are usually visable on the front page for about twelve hours.)

What are good ways of alleviating this problem, assuming it is a problem?

Comment: Arbitrarily suspending 90% of the users.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Well, your suggestion would be effective, but I doubt whether those suspended would consider it "good."

Comment: I didn't say it's a good solution. It's just a solution. We can also incite World War III; solar flares; sharks in reverse scuba suits; the big crunch; supernova the sun; summon Cthulu; other various apocalyptic catastrophes which will certainly cull the interest in mathematics, in the internet, and otherwise life on this planet.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: While I appreciate the humor in your comment, I was hoping, perhaps naively, for more practical suggestions.

Comment: My point is that there's not much that you can do about it.

Comment: Thank you all the same. I'll try to use the features of the site intelligently.

Comment: And don't go releasing The Destroyer of Worlds from his unspeakable prison! If you want an Armageddon, at least make it monsters free.

Comment: Just to clarify: You are asking from the point of a person who asks the question? (I.e., it is the problem for you because your question is visible on the front page only for very limited amount of time.) Or are you asking from a point of view of user who mostly reads and posts answers? (So you see it a problem because the questions go fast away from the frontpage and you might miss some interesting posts.)

Comment: Some of suggestions mentioned [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/20698) might help to get some attention for your question, after it was moved away from the frontpage.

Comment: BTW you said that questions get away from the front page after a few minutes. What exactly *a few minutes* means depends heavily on how the users view the site (and many other factors). Just check how long it takes for question to second page if you are viewing [50 posts per page](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions?pagesize=50&sort=active&page=2) compared to [15 posts per page](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions?pagesize=15&sort=active&page=2).

Answer (score 10):

I agree with Asaf Karagila's comment that there is not much we can do, still I share what helped me a little.

If you are not interested enough in all tags, then you can ignore some of them. Recently I have done exactly this to alleviate this issue. Doing so I managed to increase about 75% the time a question is visible on the front page.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: @JW You are welcome!

Answer (score -11):

Sometimes I will make a small but non-trivial revision to my question in order to have it revisit the front page.

Often, I randomly get responses from questions I asked years ago, and suddenly it resonates now.  It's a good thing.

---

**In a loud and crowded room, the one who gets attention will be the one who speaks loudest.**

---

Instead of channeling your anger towards me,

## isn't it time for the admins to write a nice e-mail to StackExchange addressing their problem?

The volume of the site is a measure of its success but potentially it's downfall.  Not my fault.

Comment: Thus pushing another question off the front page. It's called being selfish.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi can you phrase that in a way that doesn't cast **moral judgement**?

Comment: Sure, I can. But why should I? If you really want, I can say "This *may* solve *your* problem, but it doesn't solve *the website's* problem, and if everyone started doing this the website would be much worse for the change. So it's not a solution." But I think this easily follows from my previous comment. If you want to further your analogy (you put it in boldface, so you must think it's important): ***If everyone starts shouting at 150 decibels, then no one can hear what anyone has to say.*** (There, bold *and* italics!)

Comment: Please don't do that.

Comment: I am not sure why this discussion needs to escalate that much. If somebody has a year-old question that is unanswered and they still care about it and they edit it mildly to make it resurface, I cannot get upset about that. Okay, they could also chip in the 50 points for the bounty to do it "correctly" but in the end this technicality is not that relevant to me. Of course, if somebody were to edit there fresh question every other hour to make it stay on top, that'd be abusive in my opinion. I make a second try for the edit; the current format breaks the layout completely it is major pain.